# Add a new entry in the right click menu

Tags: java, eclipse, menu, command

I want to create a new entry in the right click menu in eclipse.

When I right click on a class, there should be a new entry 'MyEntry'.

When clicking on it it should do something like "Hello World".

Right click on a class -> MyEntry

I used a tutorial "Vogella" but it doesnt work for me.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html#contribute
Chapter 8.

Can anyone help me?
Maybe someone can tell how it works or knows a better link.

Thank you!

Comment: "*it doesnt work for me"*  1) Try describing a) What you expected to happen b) What actually happened, and for utility c) Why you expected (a) to happen.

Comment: When I run the project, I should be able to right click on a class and choose the new entry. But the new entry isnt there. even when opening a new plug in project like Sam Su told me below, the entry isnt there.

Comment: Ok, I found the reason! I does not work on java projects! How useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your situation,it's better that you build a plugin project from the new project wizard,and choose the template "Plug-in with a pop-up menu".You can get it out from the source code and the plugin.xml that how Eclipse do it programmtically.

This link may be also helpful:
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_basicext_popupMenus.htm

Comment: Hello, thank you for the tip! Unfortunately I still cant get it to work. I created a plug in project with pop up menu and run it as Eclipse Apllication. In the second workspace I right clicked on a class, but still no menu there. Do I do something wrong?